MobilePush Detail Extract Report and ActivityId
We are trying to make use of the MobilePush Detail Extract Report, to understand how our journey is performing.
Our problem is that when reading the data from the report, we noticed that there is now information whatsoever related to the Journey that generated that push, with the exception of the MessageName which is the same as the ActivityName of the journey.
The problem is that, we might have Activities with the same name for different journeys, so this is not a solution for us, and even if no duplicated names exists, the journey might have different versions, thus, the contact might receive that push more than once.
Some one can help me?
